# mysql select id and count in one command?

Tags: mysql

Using Mysql How would i merge these two commands into one?

```
select id from User where name='name'
select count(*) from Msg where user_id=@id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join the tables:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM User a
INNER JOIN Msg b ON a.id = b.user_id
WHERE a.name = 'name'
```